# How to change empty input value to empty array?

Tags: swift

```swift
var input = [readLine() ?? ""]
```

If I just entered, input has `[""]`

If I do not input anything, I want to make the input an empty list.

How can I do it?

This is because I want the count of the input to be zero when the input is empty.

Comment: How many different array elements would you like to be able to enter at once? Would it only be an empty input or one element or do you need for it to allow multiple elements to be entered at once?

Comment: @JudeMolloy just an empty input. i want to set the return value of `input.underestimatedCount` to 0 when i enter an empty value (ie when the enter key is pressed).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an IF statement to check if the input was an empty string and if so, then set the input to an empty array. There may be a better way to do this but I think this will work.

```
if input == [""] {
    input = []
}
```

I hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Simply filter out empty values:

```
input = input.filter { !$0.isEmpty }
```

or even:

```
let input = [readLine()]
   .compactMap { $0 } // remove nil
   .filter { !$0.isEmpty } // remove empty strings
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to define your own function that reads the line or returns an empty array:

```
private func myReadLine() -> [String] {
    let line = readLine()
    if line == [""] {
        return []
    } else {
        return line
    }
}
```

And then at the call site you can write:

```
var input = myReadLine()
```

Which keeps the logic separated from the calling code and is easier to read. It also has the added advantage of being a lot easier to change if you want to amend your input handling conditions later on.